# How to simply make a sound or a beep in wp7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, audio

I just wan't to make a sound to remind my user there is a new message,I don't want to use `mediaElement`.Is there any other choice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the Microsoft.Xna.Framework assembly reference to your project.

```
var stream = TitleContainer.OpenStream("cat.wav");
var effect = SoundEffect.FromStream(stream);
FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
effect.Play();
```

Comment: Where should I put my sound file?

Comment: Assuming you're using Silverlight and not XNA Game Studio: http://www.ehow.com/how_7255363_play-audio-silverlight-2_0.html